# How to arrange wxWidgets inside a frame using wxBoxers?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to use a wxSizer to arrange widgets inside a panel. I can see that widgets are arranged but they do not go inside the frame. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import wx

class MyRegion(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):        
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self,-1,pos=(70,200), size=(300,300))
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour((128,128,128)) # dark grey       

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        b1 = wx.Button(self, label="TEXT1")
        b2 = wx.Button(self, label="TEXT2")
        b3 = wx.Button(self, label="TEXT3")

        sizer.Add(b1)
        sizer.Add(b2)
        sizer.Add(b3)

        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Fit(self.panel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    myRegion = MyRegion()
    myRegion.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the panel the parent of buttons instead of the frame.

```
b1 = wx.Button(self.panel, label="TEXT1")
```

The reason for this is that although the sizers control the positioning of the items the parent/child relationship in the UI is still controlled by the wx objects that map directly to the underlying OS controls.